# Apache redirect URL to another virtualhost

Tags: redirect, rewrite, apache2, subdomain, website

I have two sites which runs independently on my VPS, let's call them site1 and site2.

They are respectively located at /var/www/html/site1 and /var/www/html/site2

I don't have a domain name yet but I can acces my site using server IP, let's say its adress is 8.8.8.8

I currently have two separate apache configuration file for each site.

Both sites are configured as follow, only `DocumentRoot` and the second `Directory` block differs.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 8.8.8.8
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/site>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I can acces both my site by enabling one and disabling the other one.

At first I wanted to have a separated subdomain http://site2.8.8.8.8/* but since I don't have a DNS record yet I can't really achieve it without modifying the local hosts file on every computer which wants to acces website.

So I though a better solution could be to have site1 running on http://8.8.8.8/* and site2 running on http://8.8.8.8/site2/*

Apparently it can be done using `RewriteCond` but I can't find a way to make it work.

Is my aim really achievable without having DNS records ?

Otherwise couldn't that be achieved by running site2 on another port like 8080 and redirecting to this port ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to do it

I just created an apache configuration inspired from phpmyadmin one.

- site1 is defined as a virtualhost in apache site
- site2 is defined as an Alias in apache configuration

Here are the minimal configuration files for those interested

```
# cat /etc/apache2/site-enabled/site1.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 8.8.8.8
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
</VirtualHost>


# cat /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/site2.conf
Alias /site2 /var/www/html/site2

<Directory /var/www/html/site2>
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```